# jquery ui sortable when list expands out of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I currently have a large list that can be ordered using the `sortable` jquery plugin. The problem is that if the user want to take an item from the top of the list and drag it to the bottom it's very clunky. you need to keep moving/giggling the mouse in order for the window to scroll.

HTML

```
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">List Item</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">List Item</li>
    // 50+ more list items
</ul>
```

JS

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
```

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rmSgx/490/

Is there a fix that enables the user to drag the list item down and it to auto scroll until the user is at their preferred spot in the list?

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible, but if you do not mind having an alternative, I would say you could use double column list where the other column is a temp column. So the user could just position his list to the point he wants and then just switch back the item from temp to permanent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by triggering a scroll action when the mouse is within the parameters of the edge and is in `out` mode event.

you can't do this based on the viewport though, you need to do this by a container.

In your example I've set the containing list element to the height of the view-port minus `50px`. this gives a gap top and bottom to allow the action to be invoked.

```
$('#sortable').css({height: ($(window).height()-50) + 'px'});
var scroll = '';
var $scrollable = $("#sortable");

function scrolling() {
  if (scroll == 'up') {
    $scrollable.scrollTop($scrollable.scrollTop() - 20);
    setTimeout(scrolling, 50);
  } else if (scroll == 'down') {
    $scrollable.scrollTop($scrollable.scrollTop() + 20);
    setTimeout(scrolling, 50);
  }
}

$("#sortable").sortable({
  scroll: false,
  out: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.helper) return;
    if (ui.offset.top > 0) {
      scroll = 'down';
    } else {
      scroll = 'up';
    }
    scrolling();
  },
  over: function(event, ui) {
    scroll = '';
  },
  deactivate: function(event, ui) {
    scroll = '';
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kplcode/rmSgx/492/